# webBrowser Navigating url

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, browser

this code doesn't work why?

```
private void web_FBCheck_Navigating(object sender, WebBrowserNavigatingEventArgs e)
{
    if (web_FBCheck.Url.ToString() == ("http://facebook.com/"))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Welcome to Facebook");
        textBox3.Text = web_FBCheck.Url.ToString();
    }            
}
```

or use `if (web_FBCheck.Url.ToString() == "http://facebook.com/")` without `( )` in the link

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? What did you expect, what is the value of `web_FBCheck.Url`, are you connecting using SSL?

Comment: does not appear the message and textBox is empty

Comment: no ssl, i have set web_FBCheck url to 'http://facebook.com/'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd guess it's because you're handling `Navigating` instead of `Navigated`, and possibly because of URL formatting. You should be doing something like this instead:

```
private void web_FBCheck_Navigating(object sender, WebBrowserNavigatingEventArgs e) {
    if(e.Url.Host.ToLower().IndexOf("facebook.com") > -1) {
        MessageBox.Show("Welcome to Facebook");
        TextBox3.Text = web_FBCheck.Url.ToString();
    }
}
```